# how to write rspec test for scope in model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have following scope in Model

```
class ProductDetail < ApplicationRecord
  scope :currently_active, lambda {
    where('? BETWEEN start_time AND end_time', Time.zone.now)
  }
end
```

I created the factory for it but trying to figure out how i could write rspec for it.

I tried to do something like below

```
  subject { create(:product_detail) }

  describe '#currently_active' do
    context '#test' do
      it 'test' do
      product = build(:product_detail, start_time: Time.now, end_time: Time.now + 30.days)

      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You shouldn't test it because is Rails core functionality. Focus on bussines logic.

Comment: I have added rspec test cases for controller. I need to add test cases for scope also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test this kind of thing by making a collection, and then doing

```
expect(Mymodel.scope).to match_array(expected_collection)
```